# Registration page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working now in a web page and I'm trying to make a registration page. I'm trying to to make sure that duplicate usernames are not allowed. Here is my code but unfortunately it doesn't work. The variable temp always shows a null value. Here is my code, please help:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MOMO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuthDB;Integrated Security=True");
        conn.Open();
        String Usercheck = "select count (*) from UserLogin where Benutzername='" + tb_name.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Usercheck, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("User already exists");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void btn_reg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MOMO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AuthDB;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    string insertquery="INSERT INTO UserLogin " + " (Benutzername, Passwort ) VALUES (@lname,@lpw)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertquery,conn);


    if ((tb_name.Text.Length > 0) && (tb_passwd.Text.Length > 0) )
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname", tb_name.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lpw",tb_passwd.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        Response.Write("Registrierung erfolgreich");
        conn.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        lbl_error.Visible = true;
        lbl_error.Text = "Eingabe unvollständig";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am Taking My expalaination in little SQLquery direction

- Why Use Count?..if accidently the table has 1+ data (logic fails)
- `if Exist` helps you from Extra OverHead than `COUNT`
- Please Do refer to [THISBLOG](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2007/12/15/exists-vs-count-the-battle-never-ends.aspx)

So here comes the battle between `count` and `EXIST`

Try Replacing

```
String Usercheck = "select count (*) from UserLogin where Benutzername='" + tb_name.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Usercheck, conn);

int temp = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    if (temp == 1)
    {
        Response.Write("User already exists");
    }
    conn.Close();
```

to

```
    String Usercheck = "IF Exist( Select Benutzername from UserLogin where Benutzername='" + tb_name.Text + "'");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Usercheck, conn);

bool temp = ;

    if (temp)
    {
        Response.Write("User already exists");
    }
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks alot 4 ur answer ill try it and see if it works

Comment: no it didnt work you know u have a boolean variable = an int !!!

Comment: and if i do so = bool temp= convert.to boolean(...) it causes an exception

Comment: sorry didn't noticed the int conversion,use returned boolean as it is..it will work..sorry ..chekc the code edited it

Comment: yes i git it!! really thanx..

Comment: it works now.. i have created a new methode i called ExecuteInsert . by the methode btn_reg() i executed the condition if(true) it means show message of double username, in the contrary its will execute the insertquery!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `ToString` method on the `ExecuteScalar` result if you want an `int`? Just cast it to the correct type:

```
Int32 temp = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

As a side note: `temp` could never be null because it's a value type, did you mean it is always 0?

Comment: yes thats what i mean sorry if i edited ur answe above thats my first time here

Comment: Don't worry. Just try with this modification and let us know.

Comment: yes it works now.. i have created a new methode i called ExecuteInsert . by the methode btn_reg() i executed the condition if(true) it means show message of double username, in the contrary its will execute the insertquery!